# I'm trying to display data from mongodb but it is giving Property does not exist error

Tags: mongodb, next.js

I'm trying to display data from my database, the API is fetching data from the database but when I try to display it gives me error products.map is not a function

Here is the code I'm using to fetch data

```
"use client";

import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export default function GetProductPage() {
    const [products, setProducts] = React.useState([]);
    const getProducts = async () => {
        const response = await axios.get("/api/admin/products");
        setProducts(response.data);
    };

    React.useEffect(() => {
        getProducts();
    }, []);

return (
    <div>
        <tbody className="statement_table__body">
          {products.map((product) => (
            <tr key={product._id}>
            <td>{product.prod_name}</td>
            <td>{product.prod_price}</td>
            <td>{product.cap_return}</td>
            <td>{product.inv_return}</td>
            <td>{product.return_period}</td>
         </tr>
        ))}
        </tbody>
    </div>
    )}
```

Here is the data and error screenshot
[image: error image]

[image: error image]

Comment: The issue is that you're using Typescript (as suggested by the .tsx extension) but you haven't provided a type for the product object within your products array.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you messed up with the HTML template and inline function.

Check this [link](https://www.javatpoint.com/react-map) for more information